# Check for existence of partial solution to linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a consistent system of linear equations $Ax = b$ that has an infinite number of solutions, and each $A_{i, j} \in \{0, 1\}$.
A system with an infinite number of solutions *may* have a partial solution. For example, in the system
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} x
=
\begin{bmatrix}
9 \\
11 \\
7
\end{bmatrix}
% Note: x = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 2 \end{bmatrix}^T
$$
we can determine that $x_2 = b_2 - b_1 = 2$ because we can subtract the first row from the second row.
It would seem that the **rank does not say anything about partial solutions**.

After applying Gaussian elimination, we find that
$$
x = \begin{bmatrix}
2 + x_4 \\
2 \\
7 - x_4 - x_5 \\
x_4 \\
x_5
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It seems that we got "closer" to a solution in the sense that some variables are now expressed in terms of *fewer other variables* than in the original system.
For example, instead of $x_1 = 9 - x_3 - x_5$ we now have $x_1 = 2 + x_4$.
However, I'm not sure if Gaussian elimination **guarantees** that each variable is in its simplest form given the system.

#### Questions

- Is there an **efficient** way to determine if a system has partial solutions?
- Is it possible to determine for a given variable what the number of dependents is? (For example, for $x_2$ above this number is 0, while for $x_1$ it is 1 because it depends on 1 other variable.)

Comment: You could use the Kernel of A. In your example, one possible Kernel of A is [k0 = [0,0,-1,1,1]; k1 = [-3,0,1,1,2]]. You can note that x2 is not part of the kernel. This tells you that overall, your system has 2 degrees of freedom, and all the solutions can be expressed as x0 + C0.k0 + C1.k1, with x0 one possible solution, and C1 and C2 some real constants. I don't know if this method is the most efficient. (If this questions has still some interest, I might write a proper answer).

Comment: According to Wikipedia the kernel of A is the set of solutions to Ax=0, which seems to match the k0 and k1 you gave. However, I'm looking for partial solutions to Ax=b. But, as you say, describing the solution set in a general form would reveal the degrees of freedom, so that could be interesting. How would you even go about generating the solution set though?

Comment: With an SVD (singular value decomposition), you could solve "argmin(||x||) | Ax = b". This will give the solution x with the smallest norm. But it's probably not the most efficient way to find any solution. Once you have that solution, or any other, check if some $x_i$ is not part of any kernel vector.